# Multiple external modals problems - Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap3 to load multiple external modals. When I toggle between the different modals I get stuck with the content of the last modal. Another problem I encounter is that for some reason after loading the first modal the `close` buttons get deactivated

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
data-load-remote="contact/contact.html" data-isloaded="false"
data-remote-target="#myModal">CONTACT</a>

<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
data-load-remote="faq/faq.html" data-isloaded="false"
data-remote-target="#myModal">FAQ</a>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="Label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


$(function() {
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if (!$this.data('isloaded')) {
        if(remote) {
            $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
            $this.data('isloaded', true)
        }
    }
});
});
```

I've tried using different `id tags` and that works fine, but then I end up with loads of `modal divs`. Is there any way to use the same `div` for multiple `modals`? Anyone?

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tomtom/wGkLT/) that doesn't load the modal at all :(

Cheers

Comment: You probably need to close the old modal before opening the new one.

Comment: yes since the buttons are located on the main canvas and the modals are on top - by toggle I mean close and open a new one

Comment: Ok. What you mean is that the content of the last modal stays in the modal? Could be possible that the load method is actually appending the content? The modal HTML is the same for all modals. Try emptying `.modal-content` before loading.

Comment: ..and how would I do that?

Comment: All content is loaded in '#myModal .modal-content'. Do $('#myModal .modal-content').html('') before loading new content in the function.

Comment: Thank you Bogdan Iulian Bursuc, I am unable to get this to work. Are you able to provide a updated version of my script?

Answer (score 2):

A proper modal should include a `modal-header`, `modal-title`, `modal-body` and a `modal-footer` with accompanying elements for close buttons.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="Label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header"> <!-- bootstrap class for header in modal -->
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> <!-- bootstrap close button in modal header -->
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4> <!-- bootstrap class modal title -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> <!-- bootstrap class for modal content -->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> <!-- bootstrap class for footer and close button in modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cleanupTheModal()">Close</button>
      </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is an updated fiddle. While not using the method you have described, this provides an additional option for loading different content for 'different' modals.

http://jsfiddle.net/wGkLT/2/

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I need to have external content loaded.